# Master Deteail Page not working on Prism Module

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I have a Xamarin forms app with 3 Modules.. Im using Prism Pattern. So i followed Brian's [git](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism). From the App.cs to the MainPage my MasterPage works fine.. Also im using IconNavigationPage it works fine. Now when i to navigate to my Module, IconNavigatePage works fine but my master Page is not there..

in my App.cs

if i do this i see the master Page on my MainPage which is the entry page

```
 NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/MyMasterDetail/MainPage");
```

From my MainPage i load my Module and navigate to it
if i do this to navigate to my module the navigation Bar is there

```
await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("Dashboard");
```

in my module there is no MasterDetail but there is NavigationMaster which inherts from Content Page like this

my wish is to display masterpage in my module only..

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"

         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="ModuleA.Views.MasterNavigation"
         Title="Module A Navigation">
```

and in my initialize code  of my moduke i have this

```
var masterDetail = PrismApplication.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage;
        if (masterDetail != null)
           masterDetail.Master = new MasterNavigation();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change from

`NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/MyMasterDetail/MainPage");`

To

`NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MyMasterDetail/NavigationPage/MainPage");`

So you can do

`await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("Dashboard");`

> And it will navigate in the **context of the parent**(`NavigationPage`) of the current page (`MainPage`) **keeping the MasterDetail.**